# Deny direct file download from webserver by URL

Tags: php, html, download, webserver, htdocs

I have a website where users can login and are identified by **sessions** and `$user[id]`. They can upload files. Files are stores in *htdocs/uploads*. Every file data is stored in a table to have a link between filename, location and user_id. On some places on my website i give the possibility to download the file by: `<a href="' . $row['path'] . '" target="_blank" download>Download file</a>`.

Behind `$row['path']` a URL like *domain.com/uploads/filename.jpg* is given. If the user know this URL path he can download the file also without login or identification by entering the URL into a browser. I want to avoid this. How can i ensure, that only files can be downloaded from *htdocs/uploads* by click on such a download link on my website.

=> I am not able to create a folder outside htdocs
=> I have tried to change the folder permissions but w/o success
=> My website is basically made in PHP, a solution in PHP is prefered.

Any idea/help available? Thank you!

Comment: You can create a file service proxy and in `.htaccess` file, you can use `Rewrite` rule to redirect requests to your proxy which would check for user session first.
This might help you out: https://medium.com/@ignasposka/restricting-public-access-for-files-on-apache-server-fbb124b862e0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to go down the route of making PHP serve the file for you. This will ensure that you can validate user credentials before serving the file.

See examples on php.net [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php). This will explain how to serve files from PHP using `header()`. This [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/316814/php-serve-a-file-for-download-without-providing-the-direct-link) also outlines some of the key concepts.

Once you've done this, you can deny direct access to these files using [htaccess rules](https://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/apache/115/htaccess-file-dir-security.html). This will ensure users can only access the files via the php endpoints, and those endpoints can perform validation of the user's credentials.

Comment: Thanks. This was the right hint for me. See my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by doing following:

1. Added a .htaccess file in my folder *htdocs/uploads* with following content:

```html
<FilesMatch ".*">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from All
</FilesMatch>
```

2. Created a file: file_download.php with following content:

```html
// Doing here some user verification based on the session and user_id
if($user['id'] != 'something i want to be') {
die('Not allowed to download this file'); 
} else {
// Verify the download as requested
    // Basic file name
    $file = basename($_GET['file']);

    // Path where the file should be stored
    $file = 'uploads/'.$file;

    if(!file_exists($file)){ // file does not exist
        die(''.$file.' file not found');
    } else {
        header("Cache-Control: public");
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
        header("Content-Type: application/zip");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

        // read the file from disk
        readfile($file);
    } 
}
```

3. Changed the download link from `<a href="' . $row['path'] . '" target="_blank" download>Download file</a>` to `<a href="file_download.php?file=<?= $row['path'] ?>Download</a>`

This way is blocking any try to download a file by using clear URL in the browser. the file can only be downloaded by having a **user identification** and the **provided link from my website**. If someone does not need the user verification, just delete the first `if/else` in the `file_download.php`.